# Swift 3 - Update key:value in dictionary in an array of dictionaries after comparison. Please assist

Tags: ios, dictionary, for-loop, swift3, compare

I have an array of dictionaries that I get as a JSON response to a URL

```
JSONResponse1 = 
[{"id":"100", "name":"Matt", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"TBC"}
,{"id":"110", "name":"Sean", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"TBC"}
, {"id":"120", "name":"Luke", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"TBC"}]
```

I have another array of dictionaries that I get as a JSON response to another URL

```
JSONResponse2 = 
[{"id":"100", "address":"1 Main Street"}
, {"id":"120", "address":"3 Main Street"}]
```

Both these response are linked by the key "id". I want to compare JSONResponse2 against JSONResponse1, and update JSONResponse1 so as to show the addresses as well. So the output of JSONResponse1 becomes:

```
JSONResponse1 = 
[{"id":"100", "name":"Matt", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"1 Main Street"}
,{"id":"110", "name":"Sean", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"TBC"}
, {"id":"120", "name":"Luke", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"3 Main Street"}]
```

**Note that all "id"s are not always present in JSONResponse2, in that case I want to leave it as it is**

Here is my attempt:

```
    for item in JSONResponse2.enumerated() {
        for var items in JSONresponse1 {
            if item.element["id"] == items["id"] {
                let address_correct = item.element["address"] as! String
                items["address"] = address_correct

                self.finalDictionary.append(items)

            } else {
                self.finalDictionary2.append(items)
            }
        }
    }
```

But this creates a really long finalDictionary2, because of for loop repetition. Any way around this?

Comment: did my suggestion work?

Comment: Thanks Milan it did, but I changed it a bit. In both cases I append to self.finalDictionary so as to have one updated "response". Your solution created two separate updated "responses". But your suggest to have the new loop was spot on! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it happens, because of the `else` branch in the inner loop, which is not executed when the item from JSONResponse1 is not present in JSONResponse2, but is executed when the current item from JSONresponse1 is not equal to current item from JSONresponse2 - which is by far not the same thing as what you want.

Drop the `else` branch and add a new `for` loop after that, which will take care of finding those items that are not in JSONresponse2. So something like this:

```
for item in JSONResponse2.enumerated() {
    for var items in JSONresponse1 {
        if item.element["id"] == items["id"] {
            let address_correct = item.element["address"] as! String
            items["address"] = address_correct

            self.finalDictionary.append(items)

        }
    }
}

for item in JSONResponse1 {
    if !(JSONresponse2.contains { (item2) -> Bool in
        return item["id"] == item2["id"]
    }) {
        self.finalDictionary2.append(item)
    }
}
```